# Spring Maven JUnit NoClassDefFoundError:org/springframework/context /ApplicationContextException

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, junit

I have created a spring legacy project using Spring STS and xml configuration file `spring-context.xml`. I am trying to test my DAO class using JUnit (**Run as > Maven test**) but I get the following error:

```
initializationError(net.mozaikdev.samples.dao.test.AddressDAOTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:123)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.resolveContextLoader(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:467)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:357)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:303)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:135)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.<init>(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:165)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 38 more
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this exception since I have declared in my pom.xml the dependency to spring-context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.mozaikdev</groupId>
<artifactId>eshop-sample-spring-legacy</artifactId>
<name>eshop-sample-spring-legacy</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository> 
        <id>repository.spring.release</id> 
        <name>Spring GA Repository</name> 
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url> 
    </repository>

    <repository> 
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id> 
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name> 
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>5.0.0.RC3</org.springframework-version>
    <org.hibernate-version>5.2.10.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.8.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MariaDB Connector J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is my JUnit test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AddressDAOTest {

@Autowired
private AddressDAO addressDAO;

private static final String STREET_1 = "street_1";
private static final String STREET_2 = "street_2";
private static final Integer ZIP_CODE = new Integer(1234);
private static final String CITY = "city";
private static final String REGION = "region";
private static final String COUNTRY = "country";
private static final Boolean IS_DELIVERY_ADDRESS = new Boolean(false);

@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(value = true)
public void testPersistAndFindById() {

    Address address = new Address();
    address.setStreet_1(STREET_1);
    address.setStreet_2(STREET_2);
    address.setZipCode(ZIP_CODE);
    address.setCity(CITY);
    address.setRegion(REGION);
    address.setCountry(COUNTRY);
    address.setIsDeliveryAddress(IS_DELIVERY_ADDRESS);

    addressDAO.persist(address);

    Long id = address.getId();

    address = addressDAO.findById(id);

    Assert.assertEquals(STREET_1, address.getStreet_1());
    Assert.assertEquals(STREET_2, address.getStreet_2());
    Assert.assertEquals(ZIP_CODE, address.getZipCode());
    Assert.assertEquals(CITY, address.getCity());
    Assert.assertEquals(REGION, address.getRegion());
    Assert.assertEquals(COUNTRY, address.getCountry());
    Assert.assertEquals(IS_DELIVERY_ADDRESS, address.getIsDeliveryAddress());

}

@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(value = true)
public void testFindAll() {

    Address address1 = new Address();
    address1.setStreet_1(STREET_1);
    address1.setStreet_2(STREET_2);
    address1.setZipCode(ZIP_CODE);
    address1.setCity(CITY);
    address1.setRegion(REGION);
    address1.setCountry(COUNTRY);
    address1.setIsDeliveryAddress(IS_DELIVERY_ADDRESS);

    Address address2 = new Address();
    address2.setStreet_1(STREET_1_UPDATE);
    address2.setStreet_2(STREET_2_UPDATE);
    address2.setZipCode(ZIP_CODE_UPDATE);
    address2.setCity(CITY_UPDATE);
    address2.setRegion(REGION_UPDATE);
    address2.setCountry(COUNTRY_UPDATE);
    address2.setIsDeliveryAddress(IS_DELIVERY_ADDRESS_UPDATE);

    addressDAO.persist(address1);
    addressDAO.persist(address2);

    List<Address> addressesList = addressDAO.findAll();

    Assert.assertNotNull(addressesList);
    Assert.assertTrue(addressesList.size() >= 2);
    Assert.assertTrue(addressesList.contains(address1));
    Assert.assertTrue(addressesList.contains(address2));
}
}
```

And finally the `application-context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Enable annotation configuration -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scan packages for Spring annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="net.mozaikdev.samples.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.mozaikdev.samples.dao.test" />

<!-- Database connection configuration -->
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${spring.datasource.jdbcUrl}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.password}"/>
    <property name="poolName" value="${spring.datasource.hikari.poolName}"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout}"/>
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="${spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTestQuery}"/>
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="${spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime}"/>
</bean>

<!-- HikariCP datasource bean -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="hikariConfig"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enables annotation-driven transaction management. -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!--
    Creates the transaction manager bean that integrates the used JPA provider with the
    Spring transaction mechanism.
-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Specifies the default settings that are compatible with Hibernate. -->
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

<!-- Creates the Hibernate entity manager factory bean -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.mozaikdev.samples.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Enable support for annotation-driven Spring MVC controllers -->
<!-- <mvc:annotation-driven/> -->
```

I have cleaned my project using **Run as > Maven clean** and **Project > Clean...**, and I updated the project **Maven > Update project** but nothing works. I am stuck now, if somebody can help me to solve this exception it would be great?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on root cause error.
It's clear enough:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException

Put Spring lib in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just edited my post and added the pom.xml and I have spring-context dependency declared, so I don't understand what's the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved that. When I ran **run as > maven install** it gave me the following error:

```
 maven error reading C:\Users\569128763\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.0.RC3\spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

So the jar file for spring-context was corrupted, I just deleted the springframework directory from my m2 repository and did **Maven > Update project**, then launched maven install once again and it worked.